# IceCast 2.3.2-kh29 server streaming 404 Error

Tags: http, audio, streaming, http-status-code-404, icecast

I am loading a MP3 stream from IceCast 2.3.2-kh29 server in the Android app with MediaPlayer class.
Playing works well, but sometimes stops happen. If see the server responses in IcyStreamMeta class for ID3 tags, there is 404 error for this case.
Also it happens in Windows 7: Firefox and other browsers.

Here are normal headers (some data ***ed):

```
    http://***:14534/***.mp3

GET /***.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: ***:14534
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.1
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2013 21:22:00 GMT
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
icy-br: 192
ice-audio-info: bitrate=192;samplerate=44100;channels=2
icy-description: MP3 192 Kbps
icy-genre: ***
icy-name: ***
icy-pub: 1
icy-url: ***
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
```

So, the stream sometimes plays only about a minute or less, sometimes seconds and stops. What's the possible reason of 404 error? In other devices there were tests with stable work. Internet speed is well. Can router cause such things? Also, maybe some special HTTP request headers are needed for IceCast (and if they're not present, it gives 404)? Or it's an internal server error for some cases?

```
So, from WireShark:
2973    53.630385000    SERVER'S IP 192.168.100.6   TCP 1466    14534 > 59847 [ACK] Seq=1284017 Ack=1 Win=63 Len=1412
2976    53.636352000    SERVER'S IP 192.168.100.6   TCP 1157    14534 > 59847 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1285429 Ack=1 Win=63 Len=1103
2978    53.671606000    SERVER'S IP 192.168.100.6   TCP 60  14534 > 59847 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1286532 Ack=1 Win=63 Len=5
2980    53.678606000    SERVER'S IP 192.168.100.6   TCP 60  14534 > 59847 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1286537 Ack=2 Win=63 Len=0
```

Comment: When you say it stops, what specifically happens?  Does the server disconnect the client?  Does the client disconnect from the server?  Can you upload a packet capture with the problem actually occurring.

Comment: I don't know, how to determine this? Causes FileNotFoundException, or 404.

Comment: In your example, there is a 200.  A 404 cannot occur mid-stream.  It sounds like your source client is randomly disconnecting.

Comment: If look at IceCast bug fixes, there are some cases of 404 error, so there's a possibility that it's something other. I get this error by seeing ID3 tags, which are loaded every 5 secs.

Comment: How to prevent from disconnecting and what's possible reasons of that?

Comment: Icecast has nothing to do with ID3 tags.  Your encoder sends other metadata.  Possible reasons for disconnecting are usually that your encoder stopped sending data, as I had said before.  At this point, it isn't clear to me what is giving a 404 and when.  If you could post a packet capture of the problem, that would show what the issue is immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Could you recommend a tool for seeing that in details?

Comment: Is it known that IceCast 2.3.2-kh29 works with Android MediaPlayer fine? From which Android version?

Comment: Check out Wireshark for digging into the raw packets being sent.  I've had trouble with Icecast and Android in the past, but it varies from build to build of Android.  Also, some devices implement hardware codecs, meaning they can differ in support of certain types of streams.

Comment: Thanks. So don't you know official information about min version of Android MediaPlayer that supports progressive HTTP MP3 streaming (there is some contradictory info) and IceCast particularly? Now checking with Wireshark.

Comment: Oh, if you can get a server to send a proper stream without chunked encoding, it will work all the way down to Android 2.1 at least.  2.3 and later have mixed results with chunked encoding.  Icecast doesn't use chunked encoding at all.  Android isn't the issue here.  It's total compatibility, from encoding, protocol, codec, etc.  There are a lot of variables.  I've skipped all of that and just wrote my own code, which is quite compatible with Android, for that very reason.  This also gives me better control over buffering and what not to optimize for mobile networks.

Comment: But I receive such response as above with Transfer-Encoding: chunked. Strangely...

Comment: Updated info on the top. From WireShark

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your chunked encoding.  You're proxying your stream through Nginx, and Nginx is "fixing" the output to be compatible with HTTP/1.0.  Don't do that.

You can try turning off chunked encoding in your Nginx config:

```
chunked_transfer_encoding off
```

Comment: Thanks. The server is not mine, I'm the developer of the app for Android. I'll try this to fix. Also I can test on other MP3 streams if something happens like this. Is chunked encoding causes these errors independently of client OS and player, or it's especially Android problem?

Comment: @Tramway11, Try http://143.226.75.100/waug_mp3_128k.  That's one of my servers with custom software.  There should be no chunked encoding.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. The error above happens not always, but sometimes.

Comment: So without "chunked_transfer_encoding" the server needs to give the Content-Length. What this will be in the case of MP3 stream, when there is no end of file? And if chunked_transfer_encoding is on, what makes the server to give 0 length chunk? Your stream works normally so far...